# Erro ao gerar PDF com RotativaW7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013, pdf

Galera, estou tendo um problema aqui para gerar um pdf com os dados vindos do banco. Meu sistema tem um cadastro de alunos e suas ocorrências. O que eu queria é que, na hora de detalhar os dados, pudesse imprimir esses os dados que já vem na tela(os dados do aluno e as ocorrências relacionadas a ele), pois quando se detalha um aluno, é um específico escolhido da Index(lista total de alunos). Frisando aqui, eu estou usando a biblioteca RotativaW7, que suporta caracteres especiais brasileiros !

O que acontece é que eu fiz tudo com base em um tutorial que tem neste link: 
http://cleytonferrari.com/gerando-relatorios-em-pdf-com-rotativa-w7/, mas eu acho que estou errado, me gerando esse erro aqui:
Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
Nessa exata linha:

    var modelo = new Aluno

Vou colocar o código que estou usando aqui:

## Controller

```
public ActionResult GeraPDF(long? id)
    {
        Aluno aluno = db
             .Alunos
             .Include(x => x.Ocorrencias)
             .AsNoTracking()
             .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);

        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
        {
            ViewName = "GeraPDF",
            Model = modelo,
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageMargins = new Margins { Bottom = 2, Left = 2, Right = 2, Top = 2}
        };
        return pdf;
    }
```

## View(usada como base pra montar o pdf)

```
@model CEF01.Models.Aluno

         <div>
           <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome) <br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Foto)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <img src="@Model.Foto" border="0" width="150px" height="160px" />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomePai)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomePai)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeMae)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomeMae)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Endereco)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Endereco)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataDeNascimento)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataDeNascimento)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnoLetivo)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AnoLetivo)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ano)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ano)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Turma)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Turma)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Numero)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Numero)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Turno)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Turno)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefone)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telefone)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefoneContato)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TelefoneContato)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefoneResponsavel)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TelefoneResponsavel)<br />
    </dd>

            </dl>
             </div>

           <br />
          <hr />
                  <h3>Ocorrências</h3>
               <br />
               @Html.Partial("PartialDetalhesOcorrencias", Model.Ocorrencias)
```

Ocorrendo erro quando se busca a imagem do aluno: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Foto)

O erro acontece assim que eu clico no link pra exibir no navegador o pdf pra ser impresso.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Qual a necessidade de criar outro objeto? Não dá pra passar o `aluno` diretamente no Model?

Comment: Então, eu num sei, pois to seguindo o tutrial que ta no link, e de acordo com o tutorial, cria-se esse outro objeto... Não entendi também, mas eu estava seguindo né.

Comment: Experimente passar `aluno` diretamente e veja o que acontece.

Comment: tirando essa parte "...new Aluno.." e deixando só a parte da lambida pra puxar os dados e as ocorrencias certo ?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Vou colocar como resposta.

Comment: Beleza, estou tentando aqui !

Comment: Érik, nossas edições colidiram, [confira os acertos que fiz](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/19361/revisions), é melhor usar o Markdown em vez de HTML

Comment: Poxa cara, valeu mesmo ! Brigadão, tentei até usar, mas acho que ainda não entendi, e valeu por esclarecer melhor !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema. O que estava acontecendo é que eu não estava passando o Id do aluno específico, então o objeto vinha como null. Então para resolver o problema, eu fiz a seguinte adaptação:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Imprimir", "GeraPDF", new { id = Model.Id})
```

Explicando: Ele mostra a palavra imprimir no link, ao ser clicado ele vai no controller onde esta a action GeraPDF, e mostra a página, buscando o Id do aluno que está em hidden.
Simples !

Answer (score 2):

O pacote RotativaW7 não esta mais ativa! Quando for utilizar **use o Rotativa**.

Na época o pacote não aceitava acentuação, ai fizemos um fork e corrigimos isso! Entramos em contato com o autor do Rotativa e ele aceitou nossa correção, e agora o Rotativa aceita acentuação!

Eu escrevi um post atualizado (usando o Rotativa) para a comunidade TI Selvagem [Rotativa PDF em ASP .Net MVC](http://www.tiselvagem.com.br/desenvolvimento/asp-net/mvc-rotativa-pdf/)

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição ai pessoal!

Comment: Cara, eu consegui usar o W7 numa boa. Instalei e tal e consegui gerar o pdf tranquilamente !

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo necessidade de montar o segundo objeto. Possivelmente ele que esteja ocasionando o erro.

```
public ActionResult GeraPDF(long? id)
{
    var aluno = db
         .Alunos
         .Include(x => x.Ocorrencias)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);

    if (aluno != null) {
        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
        {
            ViewName = "GeraPDF",
            Model = aluno,
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageMargins = new Margins { Bottom = 2, Left = 2, Right = 2, Top = 2}
        };

        return pdf;
    } else {
        // levantar erro
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Não sei que erro você teve, mas essa declaração

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Foto)
```

Pede que você tenha no Model o seguinte:

```
[Display(Name = "Foto")]
public String Foto { get; set; }
```

Comment: Agora ta dando erro no html que criei.... A nem e eu achando que ia ser tranquilo ! Ta dando erro no razor, e é o mesmo erro do anterior, não tá achando o objeto...

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Atualize sua pergunta com o erro pra eu poder atualizar a resposta.

Comment: beleza, vou colocar o erro que ta dando e a view que to usando como base pra gerar o pdf

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Mas no meu model tem esse atributo. Se eu detalhar no sistema, a foto aparece normal... So na geração do pdf que da esse erro....

Comment: Cigano, ta acontecendo alguma coisa de errado. Pois ele ta gerando erro na view toda. Agora ele não está encontrando o nome do aluno...

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Colocando o breakpoint nesta linha: `var pdf = new ViewAsPdf`, como está o objeto `aluno`?

Comment: Ta vindo como null... E não entendo porque....