# Imprimir consultas

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma view em minha aplicação em asp.net mvc que permite ao usuário realizar uma busca, a qual retorna nome e dados daquela busca. Eu queria poder imprimir esse resultado da busca. Como eu faço para imprimir div ou table?

Minha view:

```
<div> 
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
         IEnumerable<Banco.Models.Perfil> modelPerfil = (IEnumerable<Banco.Models.Perfil>)ViewBag.Perfil;
         <h4>Pesquisa por Dados</h4> <br />
       <div>  <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" placeholder="Digite a busca" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="submit">Filtrar</button></div>   <br/> <br>
     }
</div>
<table>

    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <tr>
        <th>Nome </th>
        <th>Experiência</th>

    </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td width="30%">@item.Perfil.Nome<b></td> 
                    <td width="50%">@item.Atividades <b></td>
                   @* <td>@item.Perfil.Chapa</td>*@
                    <td>
                      |&nbsp;  @Html.ActionLink("Ver Dados", "Details", "Relatorio", new { userName = @item.Perfil.Chapa }, null)|
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa(string texto)
    {
        ViewBag.Perfil = db.Perfis.AsEnumerable();
        return View(db.Experiencia.Where(x => x.Atividades.Contains(texto)).OrderBy(x => x.NomeEmpresa));
    }
```

Comment: Em qual formato você quer imprimir?

Comment: Tanto faz. Só quero poder realizar a impressão do resultado da busca.

Answer (score 3):

Aqui com base [nesse link](http://www.tiselvagem.com.br/desenvolvimento/asp-net/mvc-rotativa-pdf/) tem um tutorial bem fácil de se seguir. Eu usei e é relativamente simples, só precisa de um pouco de atenção. Lá tem como fazer, mas vou colocar os exemplos aqui pra você:

## Instalação da biblioteca

Para instalar é fácil, vá ao prompt do Nuget e instale a biblioteca Rotativa, que é ela que vai ser usada pra gerar o pdf pra ser impresso. Dessa maneira abrindo o prompt coloque:
Install-Package Rotativa(ou pra ser ficar mais igual ao prompt: PM>Install-Package Rotativa)

## Confecção da View

Essa view vai ser usada como modelo pra criação do seu relatório, ou consulta, como você quer. Lembrando aqui que esse relatório é só um exemplo, você pode customiza-lo da maneira que achar melhor:

## Modelo.cshtml

```
 @model RelatorioPDF.Models.Usuario
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Exemplo de Relatório em PDF</title>

   <!-- css -->
  <link href="~/Content/estilos-relatorio.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="cabecalho">
        <div id="nome">
            <h1>RECIBO DE DISPENSAÇÃO</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="unidade">
            <h2>Meu Sistema</h2>
            <h3>Hospital São Paulo</h3>
            <h4>Farmácia</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="corpo">
        <div class="linha">
            <p>
                Dispensado:<br />
                <span>10/10/2012</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Cartão do SUS:<br />
                <span>123.1232.123.123</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Usuario:<br />
                <span class="bold">João da Silva Gonçalves</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="linha">
            <p>
                Prescritor:<br />
                <span>Jonas São João</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Nº Registro:<br />
                <span>12323132</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Origem da Receita:<br />
                <span>10/10/012</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="linha">
            <p>Produtos Dispensados:</p>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Produto</th>
                        <th>Atendido?</th>
                        <th>Und</th>
                        <th class="aling-right">Dispensado</th>
                        <th class="aling-right">Unitário R$</th>
                        <th class="aling-right">Total R$</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td class="bold" width="45%">Anador</td>
                        <td>Sim</td>
                        <td class="fonte10">FRS</td>
                        <td class="aling-right">10</td>
                        <td class="aling-right" width="100px;">1,2345</td>
                        <td class="aling-right" style="min-width: 100px">12,23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td colspan="6" class="italico">Possologia: 1 dose, 3 vez por dia, durante 5 dias</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="bold" width="45%">Dipirona</td>
                        <td>Sim</td>
                        <td class="fonte10">FRS</td>
                        <td class="aling-right">10</td>
                        <td class="aling-right" width="100px;">1,2345</td>
                        <td class="aling-right" style="min-width: 100px">12,23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td colspan="6" class="italico">Possologia: 1 dose, 3 vez por dia, durante 5 dias</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="bold">Total</td>
                        <td class="aling-right">R$ 12,23</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="linha">
            <p>
                Observação:<br />
                <span>Paciente com fortes dores de cabeça</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rodape">
        <p>Usuário: <span>Cleyton Ferrari</span> Emitido: <span>26/10/2012</span> CleytonFerrari.com</p>
       </div>
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

## Colocando para funcionar

Depois de a view de modelo ter sido criada pra ser impressa ou salva em pdf, agora é só criar a lógica no controller pra que se seja realmente criado o pdf:

## Controller

Nesse controller, é so um exemplo, pra salientar, e você pode colocar a action de criação do modelo em qualquer controller ok ? Aqui é só um exemplo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RelatorioPDF.Models;
using Rotativa;
using Rotativa.Options;

namespace RelatorioPDF.Controllers
{
  public class RelatoriosController : Controller
{
       /*
           * Retorna a view simples em HTML, usada como modelo para gerar o PDF
        */
    public ActionResult ModeloHTML()
    {
        return View("Modelo");
    }

       /*
        * Retorna um PDF diretamente no browser com as configurações padrões
        * ViewName é setado somente para utilizar o próprio Modelo anterior
        * Caso não queira setar o ViewName, você deve gerar a view com o mesmo nome da action
     */
    public ActionResult PDFPadrao()
    {
        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
                      {
                          ViewName = "Modelo"
                      };
        return pdf;
    }

    /*
     * Configura algumas propriedades do PDF, inclusive o nome do arquivo gerado,
     * Porem agora ele baixa o pdf ao invés de mostrar no browser
     */
    public ActionResult PDFConfigurado()
    {
        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
        {
            ViewName = "Modelo",
            FileName = "NomeDoArquivoPDF.pdf",
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            IsGrayScale = true,
            PageMargins = new Margins{Bottom = 5, Left = 5, Right = 5, Top = 5},
        };
        return pdf;
    }

    /*
     * Pode passar um modelo para a view que vai ser utilizada para gerar o PDF
     */
    public ActionResult PDFComModel()
    {
        var modelo = new Usuario
                         {
                             Nome = "Cleyton Ferrari", 
                             Site = "http://cleytonferrari.com"
                         };

        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
        {
            ViewName = "Modelo",
            Model = modelo
        };

        return pdf;
    }

}
}
```

## Observações

Seguindo esse exemplo irá funcionar a geração da impressão de suas consultas tranquilamente. Agora, se for uma coisa mais dinâmica, digo, com dados vindos do banco, é só você adaptar o código e colocar a manipulação do banco, igual quando vem criadas as actions que vem com o scaffolding. Ou você pode dar uma olhada [em uma pergunta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19361/erro-ao-gerar-pdf-com-rotativaw7) que eu coloquei a action do jeito certo pra buscar os dados dinamicamente, e inclusive respondi a pergunta mostrando a forma certa de se gerar o relatório ao clicar no link.

Comment: Não é bom usar o Rotativa. Ele não funciona no Azure.

Comment: Mas se ele num for colocar no azure é uma boa. Mas você sabe porque não funciona @CiganoMorrisonMendez ?

Comment: Dá erro. Contatei o desenvolvedor e ele disse que não iria resolver.

Comment: Nossa... Que interesse dele então em relação ao um erro que ele pode resolver né... Mas tem outros que funcionam certo ?

Comment: Sim, tem o RazorPDF, que funciona em Azure. Este que eu uso nas minhas soluções: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais simples é através de um link em JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Imprimir</a>
```

Para evitar que o título seja impresso na página, use a seguinte configuração no seu Layout:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page 
        {
            size: auto;
            margin: 0mm;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Não estou usando Azure não e busco os dados do banco sim. Vou tentar o razorPDF então e para algumas pastas basta esse javascript. Testei esse javascript:windows.print e vi que retorna tudo o que aparece na minha página. Ok, em alguns casos é isso mesmo que preciso, mas se eu quiser por exemplo  não imprimir os botões e links da página, como faço?

Comment: Api você teria que preparar uma View simplificada. Não precisa ser necessariamente um PDF.

Comment: Só criando uma outra view simplificada? Não consigo de alguma forma na mesma view omitir o que não quero imprimir?

Comment: Só criando uma função JavaScript que oculte aquilo que você não quer exibir, pra depois chamar o `window.print()`.